# Transmit Data over wlan in Linux

Tags: networking, wifi, wlan

Its a repost from here : [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6607657/630661),

I am struggling to find a some tool through which I can transmit the Data through a Wireless Driver which gives me the flexibility to set for instance the DataRate, the PacketSize of the PSDU.

Here is a brief overview of my setup:

1. A laptop running Ubuntu is used as a Transmitter ( IEEE 802.11b)
2. A Dedicated Hardware which is a receiver.

I would like to use some tool ( or scripts) in the Transmitter to transmit Data and verify whether my Hardware is working properly.

So, basically, I should be having the flexibility to assign the Data Rate ( for example 1,2,5.5 or 11Mbps), set the PacketSize, Transmit Frequency etc.

Basically, I can check all these, through iwconfig, tcpdump, wireshark etc.

So, the problem is I am not able to find what wlan standard is currently being used in the wireless driver so that I can tweak around with the settings.

Just to make it clear, I am not looking for any readymade scripts or something. I am looking for some direction as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

The negotiated data rate can be controlled by the linux command line utility iw

e.g.
iw wlan0 set bitrates legacy-2.4 12 18 24

You can get the link status as well. This gives you the negotiated data rates.
e.g.

```
iw dev wlan0 link
Connected to 04:21:b0:e8:c8:8b (on wlan0)
        SSID: attwifi
        freq: 2437
        RX: 2272 bytes (18 packets)
        TX: 232 bytes (3 packets)
        signal: -57 dBm
        tx bitrate: 36.0 MBit/s
```

More info here on using iw can be found here:
http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/iw

To test data going through you can use iperf which supports all the options you need.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I was looking for such a tool. I will try this to verify my hardware. Thanks for your help